# How to convert LINQ query syntax with joins, groups and inline query to LINQ method syntax

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need to convert the following query in SQL to LINQ using the method syntax, but I'm getting confused when I try to include the inline query, joins and groupings:

```
SELECT CL.*, CB.*, CD.*, CC.*, CS.*
FROM clients AS CL
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A.client_id, SUM(A.amount) AS balance
    FROM accounts AS A
    WHERE A.account_id = 1
    GROUP BY A.client_id
    HAVING (SUM(A.amount) > 0.015) OR (SUM(A.amount) < -0.015)
) AS CB ON CL.client_id = CB.client_id
INNER JOIN client_details AS CD ON (CL.client_id = CD.client_id) AND (CL.audit_id = CD.audit_id)
LEFT JOIN client_categories AS CC ON CD.client_category_id = CC.client_category_id
LEFT JOIN statuses AS CS ON CD.status_id = CS.status_id
```

I did get the GROUP BY and HAVING portions working independently of the overall query, but I have not been able to merge this with the rest as an inline query (though I've tried .Any and other LINQ methods):

```
.Where(a => a.AccountId == 1)
.GroupBy(a => new { a.ClientId })
.Where(ag => ag.Sum(a => a.Amount) > 0.015M || ag.Sum(a => a.Amount) < -0.015M)
.Select(ag => new { Id = ag.Key.ClientId, Balance = ag.Sum(a => a.Amount) })
```

I have managed to convert it to LINQ using the query syntax, which works perfectly for me, but I need it in the method (Lambda) syntax:

```
var clients = from c in _context.Clients
              join cb in (from a in _context.Accounts
                          where a.AccountId == 1
                          group a by new { Id = a.ClientId } into g
                          where g.Sum(gs => gs.Amount) > 0.015M || g.Sum(gs => gs.Amount) < -0.015M
                          select new { g.Key.Id, Balance = g.Sum(gs => gs.Amount) }) on c.Id equals cb.Id
              join cd in _context.ClientDetails on new { c.Id, c.AuditId } equals new { cd.Id, cd.AuditId }
              join cc in _context.ClientCategories on cd.ClientCategoryId equals cc.Id into ccj
              from cc in ccj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join cs in _context.Statuses on cd.StatusId equals cs.Id into csj
              from cs in csj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new Client(c, cb.Balance, new ClientDetails(cd, cc, cs));
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why do you need it in Lambda syntax? For big queries like this query syntax is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @Magnus - I agree, but all of the project code was written in Lambda from the beginning, so I was just keeping the same standards. I prefer just writing SQL (old head going all the way back to the first versions of ODBC), but query syntax is close enough.

Comment: I think Resharper can translate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that LinqPad offers the solution. Run the LINQ query syntax against your database and, when it finishes, click the Lambda symbol at the bottom of the page to see the method syntax:

[LinqPad Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A4KV.png)

Thanks LinqPad!